# Azure Activity Log for all the users of the organization

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We want to see activity logs initiated by all the users from the organization(like users@mycompamy.com). We don't want to see the activity initiated by platform(by azure policy, by backup management, etc).

On the Azure portal, there is only two option: Either select 'All' or type a single user's name. I tried '*@mycompany.com' but it didn't work. Is there any way to get this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

In azure monitor -> Logs, you can write the query like below:

```
AzureActivity 
| where Caller contains "@mycompamy.com"
```

Add a screenshot for this:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

A simple way is that just type the `@mycompany.com` in the search box. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Another more advanced method is that nav to azure monitor -> logs -> then use kusto query, then you can query what you like as per the condition like use this where clause `EventInitiatedBy contains "@mycompany.com"`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems 'EventInitiatedBy ' does not recognize. Could you please send a sample query.

Comment: @SakaldeepYadav, I'm sorry, in the query, it should be "Caller" instead of "EventInitiatedBy". I also updated the answer by adding the sample query in azure monitor.